# Phonemes and graphemes

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
    W IY K D EY,w ee k d ay
    T EH K S T,t e x _ t
    Y UW,ewe _
    SH UW T,chu te
    SH UW T,chu te
    SH UW T,chu te !
    SX AH K,s u ck
```

where the first half of the file are phonemes, and the second half, after the comma, are graphemes. The phonemes and graphemes match one another. I want to write a function **graphemes_phonemes**, which takes in three arguments:

1. the initial csv file, **csv_file**
2. another csv file, **valid_phonemes** which contains all the valid phonemes, which looks like this:

   ```
   AA
   AE
   AH
   AO
   AW
   AY
   B
   CH
   D
   DH
   EH
   ER
   EY
   F
   G
   HH
   IH
   IY
   JH
   K
   L
   M
   N
   NG
   OW
   OY
   P
   R
   S
   SH
   T
   TH
   UH
   UW
   V
   W
   Y
   Z
   ZH
   ```
3. And an optional argument, valid_graphemes, which is a set containing all the valid graphemes, which also includes an underscore "_" character.

I want to be able to return a 4-tuple, which follows the phoneme-grapheme data in the csv file.

1. I want it to be able to return the number of invalid rows, where the number of phonemes does not match the number of graphemes. Or there are phonemes or graphemes that do not exist in the data. underscores do count, but just not things like exclamation marks. The last four rows are invalid. The first two are invalid because the lengths don't match up, the third is invalid because it have an "!", and the last is invalid because "SX" is not a valid phoneme.
2. The average number of phonemes per word.
3. the average number of graphemes per word.
4. The proportion of graphemes that have one or more underscores.

I want the last three values only to be based on rows that are valid. If a row is not valid valid, then the calculations of the last three return outputs should not be counted towards the averages of the proportions. If the last three values have a denominator of zero, then the return value should return to None.

Here is an example

```
    >>>graphemes_phonemes("csv_file.csv", valid_phonemes = "valid_p.txt")
    (4, 4.0, 4.666666666666667, 0.6666666666666666)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import csv

    def phonemes_graphemes(csv_file, valid_phonemes = "valid_p.txt")

        csv_read = open(csv_file)
        reader = csv.reader(csv_read)

        phonemes_valid = open(valid_phonemes)
        phonemes_read = csv.reader(phonemes_valid)
```

I'm just not sure how I should go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `csv.reader` for your valid phoneme or valid grapheme files, since they just contain the one value per line. I'd read them into a `set`, using something like:

```
with open(valid_phonemes) as v_ph:
    valid_phoneme_set = set(line.strip() for line in v_ph)
```

Then when you read through your CSV file, you can check each phoneme against the set with `if phoneme in valid_phoneme_set`. Here's a really quick implementation that does what I think you want:

```
valid_row_count = 0
invalid_row_count = 0
phoneme_count = 0
grapheme_count = 0
with open(csv_file, newlines="") as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file):
    for phoneme_string, grapheme_string in reader:
        phonemes = phoneme_string.split()
        graphemes = phoneme_string.split()
        if ((len(phonemes) == len(graphemes) and
             all(phoneme in valid_phoneme_set for phoneme in phonemes)
             # add another clause here to check the graphemes against some set, if you want
           ))    # doubled parentheses used to avoid ambiguous indentation
            valid_row_count += 1
            phoneme_count += len(phonemes)
            grapheme_count += len(graphemes)
        else:
            invalid_row_count += 1

phoneme_average = float(phoneme_count) / valid_row_count # float call only needed on Python 2
grapheme_average = float(grapheme_count) / valid_row_count
```

The two averages should always be the same though, since the lists of graphemes and phonemes are required to be the same length every time (or the row is invalid, and so we don't count them). If you have some other logic you want to apply to the counting of one kind of item but not the other, you just need to write an appropriate computation in place of the `len` I have above (e.g.  `sum(grapheme != "_" for grapheme in graphemes)` would exclude underscores from the count of the graphemes).